# Convert multiple columns to dates with lubridate and dplyr

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I'm looking for a straightforward way to convert all of the variables in a data frame which begin with 'date' to dates using `lubridate::dmy()` (they are currently characters with the dmy format).

I had thought there would be done with mutate_if or mutate_each in `dplyr` but I am struggling to figure out how.

Comment: something like `df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("date")), dmy)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `mutate_at()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- mutate_at(df, vars(starts_with("date")), funs(dmy))
```

or use `mutate_if` to mutate all date columns to dmy. Using `is.Date`  from `lubridate`.

```
df  <- mutate_if(df, is.Date, funs(dmy))
```